# Is Blogengine.NET a stable blogging platform?

Tags: .net, asp.net, blogs, blogengine.net

I implement many themes in Blogengine.net 2.0 for many users and have lots of problems with it then i need to thing first that are it is really stable.

1. when i use Be.net 2.0 pagination in the stable version wrongly coded they never update them even someone reported them many time. means no one care about bad thing populated  in Be.net 2.0
2. when i learn them their is too much blog but not as much as wordpress no problem but if you have a question their is no one answer you or answer you got from community going  too late. this is not like a wordpress community  then you question and get response quickly.
3. the first and 2nd is small issue no problem i have from that but a big problem is that functionality in blogengine.net not working well as in wordpress and in some other cms have every functionality well designed. i found many issue i reported from other when i implement theme from them like.

3.1 if someone write a post who are in future date , in draft , or published then sometime they show addpost page instead of editpost page. this make sometime user feel dirty because you know what they thing when they write a big post and found that all their craft goes left

3.2 Be.net have less functionality then any average other CMS no problem if it's less the issue that sometime you not found what's going wrong whenever their is a issue in the code you write or refactor existing pattern in blogengine.net

SO i want to know are Blogengine.net 2.0 really have stable version or they make them only for showing that they have really same thing as other.

the issue is not customization or implement things but if you use them then when more error or issue come who believe on it.

Comment: Blogengine.net is not a .NET platform but a bloging engine. Please rename your question. I find it hard to do because I have a hard time understanding what you are asking. It feels as if you are asking whether or not the publisher of Blogengine.NET is reliable...

Comment: I think this question belongs here: http://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions I get a feeling you are complaining more than asking a question.

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere in that text. Get to the point and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to ask. You just mentioned some problems you have encountered while using BE.NET. However here's my point of view about BE.NET:

- BlogEngine.NET is one of the most popular blog engines written under .NET Framework (Current version [BE 2.0] under .NET Framework 3.5).
- It has a very flexible widget-extension API that you can use to be able to write anything you desire.
- It's in active development and from my personal experience, they reply pretty fast about the problems users encounter on their CodePlex forum.
- It supports XML as data storage as well, which can be a very good feature for people who want to have their blog on a cheap hosting server.

Compared to Wordpress:

- BE is not nearly as big and popular as Wordpress. You should not expect such support you get on wordpress from BE team.
- Wordpress has many more ready to use addons-plugins.

I have decided to go with BlogEngine.NET, Because I'm a .NET developer and I wanted to have full control over my blog's source code. Every time I think my blog is missing something and I can't find a good solution on the internet, I write a widget/extension thanks to BE's extensible plugin architecture.

At last, If you're a .NET developer and you'd like to have a blog engine written under .NET Framework and want full control over it and don't mind writing and contributing extensions/plugins which have not been yet written, Go with BlogEngine.NET, otherwise, Wordpress might be a better choice.

Comment: i am not compare then with wordpress. wordpress have no matter here the actual problem is issue i got in blogengine.net. in 2.0 implementation i found that most of person got many kind of problem in the admin section they worked. sometime many of functionality not going to work perfectly

Comment: I have not tried BE.NET 2 yet. But I know that admin section is the most changed part of BE.NET 2.0. So there might be peoblems with it. I think if there are serious problems, they'll publish an update soo. Better to let them know on their discussion board.

Comment: they never thing about update suppose wrong pagination. they never update them even it's done in 2 second. they just care about showing less bug solved.